# Where is the right place to unzip Android Windows emulator zip file

Tags: android, android-studio

I am installing Android Studio but am having this error

```
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 31.2.10)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-8420304.zip
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: No route to host: connect.
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 31.2.10)" failed.
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: No route to host: connect.
```

I guess this error has to due with internet connection being too slow and not being able to download at https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-8420304.zip file.  I have manually downloaded **emulator-windows_x64-8420304.zip**.

My question is which android studio directory, do I have to unzip the file to get my Android Studio installations working.

[image: Screenshot Error display]

Answer (score 0):

The default location for android emulator when its downloaded from android studio is the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator
```

I haven't tried to download the emulator separately but I assume it should go to the same directory